# Internet Explorer 8 won't play midi files

Tags: internet-explorer, midi

I am building a small web application to support midi files. I've noticed a strange thing. When I try browsing the content of my website and navigating to a midi file inside it Internet Explorer won't show me the midi file player. Instead I see a broken image. Safari, Chrome and even Firefox do support it. I've installed several active-x controls, none of them seem to solve this problems. Do you know of any issues involving IE8 and midi files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who haa, this took time. In case anyone runs into the same trouble in future (and of course for whenever I forget this solution) This is a quick summary of the error I've encountered and the solution:

Background:
I am using Internet Explorer 8 and I am trying to play midi files through my browser.

Error:
The file did not load, I saw this grim broken jpeg icon. My quick time player could play the midi file, from some reason my web browser could not. Furthermore, I couldn't play any media file through browser. I kept getting this annyoing Open \ Save \ Cancel dialog.

Solution:
I found this article that helped out: 
http://www.techsupportforum.com/microsoft-support/internet-explorer-forum/62426-resolved-embedded-sounds-no-longer-work-ie-v6-under-winxp-help.html

pperently another program was using my IE 8 audio definiations and kept blocking me from playing those midi files. You can read that article for more details. If you want to force your browser to reclaim quick time's settings go here:
http://www.solitude.dk/archives/embedquicktime/

or just open quick time. It didn't work for me first, I needed to download the newest version of quick time. Once I've reclaimed the files quick time needs to play, I needed to do one extra thing. In order to allow it to play midi files:

- 1.I right clicked the quick time app
- 2.Selected plug-in settings
- 3.Went to audio tab
- 4.selected my default music synthesizer to be General Midi (I guess it can change between OSes and pcs)

I hope this will come in handy one day.

Answer (score 1):

What HTTP Content-Type response header are you sending?  Use something like [www.fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com) to check.